# Foreing key 'FK_compras' references invalid table ' '. Error al crear llaves foráneas en una tabla

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que donde tengo que crear la base de datos y sus respectivas tablas, para eso tengo la tabla **Clientes**, **Producto** y **Proveedores** de los cuales necesito relacionar, pero a la hora de agregar las llaves foraneas a las tablas me dice lo siguiente *foreign key references invalid table 'producto'* y no se en que otra forma reestructurar mi problema. Espero haberme explicado bien.

```
    --Creacion de la base de datos
      create database Ejercicio1
    --hacemos uso de la bd que creamos
     use Ejercicio1
     --creamos la tabla clientes
     create table clientes
     (DNI int primary key,
     nombre varchar(30),
     a_paterno varchar(30),
     a_materno varchar(30),
     direccion varchar(30),
     f_nacimiento date)

     --creamos la tabla compras
     create table compras
     (DNI int references clientes,
     codigo int references producto)

     --creamos la tabla producto
     create table producto
     (codigo int primary key,
     nombre varchar(30),
     precio_u money,
     NIF int references proveedor)

     --creamos la tabla proveedor
     create table proveedor 
     (NIF int primary key,
     nombre varchar (30),
     direccion varchar(30))

     select * from clientes
     select * from compras
     select * from producto
     select * from proveedor
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es realmente necesaria esa imagen?

Answer (score 2):

En este caso el error parece ser bastante simple. Al momento de crear la tabla `Compras`, que está relacionada con `Clientes` y `Producto`, aún no existe la tabla `Producto`, por eso te da ese mensaje de error.

La solución es crear la tabla `Compras` después de haber creado `Clientes` y `Producto`

Comment: La mayoría me ha dicho lo mismo, pero ya he echo primero las tablas y despues las FK(foreing key) pero me sigue marcando lo mismo

Comment: entonces por favor pon el msje de error exacto que obtienes y también el código exacto

Comment: Ese es mi código. y el mensaje de error que me pone.

Comment: No hay otro factor que me este afectando ???

Comment: pero en ese código el orden de creación de tablas está incorrecto. Acabas de comentar que cambiando el orden te tira el error también. Pon el código con el orden correcto y el mensaje de error que te lanza

Comment: quieres decir que ponga las tablas conforme vaya a ocupar las llaves foraneas??

Comment: Cuando creas una tabla y está referenciando a otra, esa otra debe existir. El orden de tus `CREATE TABLE` debería ser: 1. Clientes, 2. Proveedor, 3. Productos, 4. Compras

Comment: Lo hare de esa manera y te comento el resultado

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya no me marca el error. Fue de gran ayuda

Comment: @EddAtzin, si esta respuesta te ayudo a resolver el problema, por favor [marcala como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), y si consideras que es de buena calidad, votala a favor. Si no sabes como hacerlo, haz (de nuevo) el [tour]. Un saludo.